# CKeditor sub-numbered list plugin

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is anyone aware, if there is a plugin for creating the following list style:

```
1. First item
    1.1 Sub item
    1.2 Second sub-item
2. Second item
    2.1 Sub
    2.2 More sub
```

Essential is that sub-item gets compound number formatting, like `1.2`, `2.6` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't find one, and nobody answers, I asume there is none, at list in public access.